# Invalidate Cloudfront Cache in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, amazon-cloudfront

I'm trying to invalidate aws cloudfront cache within a rails application on save/ update, rather than doing it manually in the aws console. I've researched the aws-cloudfront gem, but nothing is making sense to me. Any help/ suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Nothing here? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/CloudFront/Client.html#create_invalidation-instance_method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future devs searching for an answer to this. I found a great solution using the [cloudfront-invalidator gem](https://github.com/reidiculous/cloudfront-invalidator) (duh). Once installed, I was able to use a callback method which invalidates everything on save/ update.

Answer (score 0):

The invalidation ideally should happen automatically because the filename being served itself is different. If this is an asset on the rails asset pipeline the finger printing feature should be working for you, but i sense that you are saving updating something else.

Comment: I thought so too. Doesn't seem to be the case though, as it's not clearing automatically

Comment: It won't clear it automatically it will simply serve another file because the filename is different.